# how to implement google instant app with NFC in android studio

Tags: android, nfc, android-instant-apps

i want to run instant app when tapping nfc tag in android studio. currently my simple instant app is crash when calling NFCAdapter.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you do not have to implement any NFC functions in your app. The NFC Tag can just redirect to the URL that you have set to open the Instant App in the AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instant Apps cannot currently access NFC hardware. The list of permissions supported by Instant Apps can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html#available-permissions) and you can see that the [`android.permission.NFC`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#manifest) is not supported.

If you want to trigger your Instant App when a NFC tag is tapped, that should work if you tie an Instant App-enabled URL to a tag. When that tag is accessed and the URL opened by the system, the Instant App should trigger instead.

Comment: thanks, One more question i want to ask is , is it possible auto connect to a fixed SSID in instant app. "android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
" is not supported in the instant app. is there any other way to auto connect.?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not supported in Instant Apps at this time (basically anything to do with changing system settings will not work). What is your use-case? Connecting to a local device like a camera?

Comment: The basic idea is to let user gain ‘premium’ WIFI access