# Limitation of the Android Instant App Permission

Tags: android, permissions, nfc, android-instant-apps

I trying to see if my app could be done in instant app. My app is based on taking the temperature sent by NFC from my ship.

Unfortunately the FAQ of android developers site says that only these following few permissions a available.

https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html

That this means that the NFC permission isn't possible?

Thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to implement google instant app with NFC in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325441/how-to-implement-google-instant-app-with-nfc-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 4):

The documentation clearly states that:

> Instant apps can use the Android permissions shown in the list that follows. Any permission not shown in the list is not available to instant apps.

So no, obtaining NFC permission (android.permission.NFC) is not possible.

Comment: So what if the full app uses NFC - is it okay to have the NFC permission in the manifest so it can be used by the full app, so long as that permission (and related API) are not invoked while it's running in Instant App mode?

Comment: I found an answer essentially saying that yes, you can declare different permissions for your installed app vs. Instant App, there's just a little nuance to it. stackoverflow.com/a/54097352/1119656