# Can I open another app's play store install prompt with InstantApps.showInstallPrompt?

Tags: android, google-api, android-instant-apps

I want to make google play install popup

Then I found these answers: [opening-google-play-in-popup-like-vimeo-wisher-buzzfeed-instant-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285281/opening-google-play-in-popup-like-vimeo-wisher-buzzfeed-instant-app/48285871#48285871)

So, I read document of [Instant Apps](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/instantapps/InstantApps)

and I have a question of InstantApps method: showInstallPrompt

In API document, showInstallPrompt method shows a dialog that allows the user to install the current instant app.

In this sentence, current instant app means my instant app?
And can I open another app(third-party app) install prompt with that method in my app or my instant app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`showInstallPrompt()` will allow the user to install the full app associated with your instant app (The one published to Google Play with the same application identifier).

Installing an instant app from a user perspective in this context just means upgrading from instant app to full app.

If you want users to install a different app, you should link to Google Play instead, as described here using intents: https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#android-app but then you lose that upgrade mechanism which migrates your instant app data to the installed app on most Android versions.