# How to show Google play store's Install slider or popup from within my app?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, interstitial

[image]

The above Google play install popup or slider is shown when I click on the Install button from the Interstitial ad. It shows the Google play installer within the app. I'd like to achieve the same. I've tried these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285281/opening-google-play-in-popup-like-vimeo-wisher-buzzfeed-instant-app), but no luck. Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: These kind of activities are prohibited and your app will be restricted after publishing.

Comment: Any reason for that? It clearly looks like Google play services are doing that. Why would the app get banned for this? @AsiriH.

Comment: Any news? This kind of slider exists in Facebook app and with some ads sdk. Why not available for everybody?