# Android: show google play dialog inside app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, google-play

I am looking for a way to show google play install app prompt dialog inside app [example: facebook ad install dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJXcZ.jpg)

This type of install dialog is also used on youtube

I tried:

```
market://launch?id=<package_name>
```

But its redirecting me to Google play app

Is there a way to use this type of dialog?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean something like that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48288676/3894304

Comment: i think its not the same thing the link you mentioned is about InstantApps